# Searching apostrophe in solr search engine

Tags: solr, lucene

What should I put in schema.xml Solr when I'm trying to query Oneall, it will get "Oneall Jr and O'neal Jr" Jr.But when I query O'neal it still get "Oneall Jr and O'neal Jr".
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  Why don't you expect that to match?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but I would suggest putting it into quotes so that your phrase rather than term matching e.g. "Oneall"